# Translate C# to Visual Basic .NET for OPC UA

Tags: opc-ua

I'm trying to create an OPC UA - Client to read Data from an OPC - Server. I am using Softing .NET Toolkit for this. But the main problem is, that the Documentation is only for C# and I'm not very familiar with C#. I know, there are some C# -> VB.NET translater on the Internet, but they don't work very well for this code.

I need to translate the following Code to Visual Basic .NET. Could someone help me with this?

How is this "method" called with this brackets "{" ? Is this a method, to join an instance of the class?

```
const string StaticValueNodeID = "ns=3;i=10221";
const string StaticValueNodeID1 = "ns=3;i=10229";
const string StaticValueNodeID2 = "ns=3;i=10228";

List<ReadValueId> listOfNodes = new List<ReadValueId>()
{
    new ReadValueId()
    {
        NodeId = new NodeId(StaticValueNodeID),
        AttributeId = AttributeId.Value
    },
    new ReadValueId()
    {
        NodeId = new NodeId(StaticValueNodeID1),
        AttributeId = AttributeId.Value
    },
    new ReadValueId()
    {
        NodeId = new NodeId(StaticValueNodeID2),
        AttributeId = AttributeId.Value
    }
};
```

Thank you very much in advance for your answer :)

Comment: object initializer, with a link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to know :) Maybe I could translate it for myself with this guide

Comment: great, I'll convert the comment to an answer so you can accept it